# Sentiment analysis tool to classify groups

Tags: twitter, machine-learning, classification, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a machine learning project and I am at the first stage of my progress. I am working on extracting features and testing that features to use or not to use. I have a dataset consisting of 2 classes. I want to check whether a relation happens between sentiments and being either one of that groups. My data looks like this:

```
group_a this is a tweet
group_b this is another tweet
group_b this is another tweet
group_a this is another tweet
```

**How can I find correlation between sentiment and groups?** Because this is a feature selection part of my project, **I can use any tools instead of implementing it by hand**. WEKA, PRTools or any other, if you can show me how to do it you are welcome.

**PS:** Actually before implementing an algorithm I want to check whether I can get something like:

**i.e. group_a is more negative than group_b**

So at my test data when I get a sentence I can say that if it is a negative sentiment sentence it may be related to group_a

Comment: can you make a detailed example, not just `this is a sentence here`. I do not quite understand your question.

Comment: So can I assume: first each tweet has only one sentiment (you can use some measure of positiveness, e.g., from -3 to 3). second when aggregating all the tweets in the group level, you expect to see the distribution of sentiment measures (the scores) is significantly different between group_a and group_b? If this is the case, you can start from collecting labeled data (the positiveness) for each tweet. Then train a classifier using the usual way (getting features like n-gram, emoticon, pos tag). Finally aggregating the prediction results of n tweets to compare the between-group correlation.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume you are trying a binary sentiment classification into positive-versus-negative sentiment. I suggest using the C4.5 decision tree classifier in Weka. If you want to go into the theoretical details of how the entropy measures employed in C4.5 model what you are trying to achieve, please take a look at Ch. 4 of [Mark Hall's thesis](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~mhall/thesis.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one nice document on how to perform Sentiment Analysis in NLTK.

> http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/

Also, scikit-learn is an open source machine learning library for the Python programming language. Since you have too classify only into 2 classes a Bernoulli Naive Bayes classifier should be able to solve your task efficiently.

> http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#bernoulli-naive-bayes

Your solution = nltk + scikit

Cheers.